# Flutter RaisedButton Hightlightelevation delay

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created the following RaisedButton in Flutter:

[image]

The problem is, the button's highlightElevation triggers when you press and hold the button for approximately 1 second when I have the image shown on the left of it, but when I remove the image, it works as intended.
Is there a way to fix this while keeping the image?

here is my code:

```
Widget systems(String systemName, String systemTitle, Image img) {
return Center(child:
Container( width:width-20,height:110,child:
Column( children: <Widget>[
SizedBox(height: 10),
RaisedButton( elevation: 10,splashColor: Colors.transparent,highlightElevation: 0, shape: 
RoundedRectangleBorder(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
), 
    color: Colors.white,
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:0,top:15,bottom:15),
        
        child: Row(children: [
          img,Container(width:width-120,child:
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(systemName, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                
              ],
            ),
          ),)
        ])))
])));
}
```

PS: I have called this widget 9 times within a for loop in another widget, and when I reduce the number of the loop to 5 or lower, the button works as intended as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to Flutter SDK  highlightElevation is for the button's Material when the button is enabled and pressed.

Please refer https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RawMaterialButton/highlightElevation.html

> highlightElevation property :
> The elevation for the button's Material when the button is enabled and pressed.